# sql filtering 2 or more

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, count, having

```
    voorletters, naam, geslacht, boete    
    B   Niewenburg  V   25.00
    B   Niewenburg  V   140.00
    D   Moerman V   35.00
    D   Moerman V   50.00
    DD  Cools   V   75.00
    DD  Cools   V   85.00
    E   Bakker, de  M   30.00
    E   Bakker, de  M   35.00
    E   Bakker, de  M   90.00
    E   Bakker, de  M   95.00
    IP  Baalen, van V   140.00
    R   Permentier  M   100.00
```

And I have this as sql statement

```
SELECT VOORLETTERS, NAAM, GESLACHT, BEDRAG
FROM SPELER S
RIGHT JOIN BOETE B ON B.SPELERSNR = S.SPELERSNR
LEFT joiN BESTUURSLID BL ON BL.SPELERSNR = S.SPELERSNR
GROUP BY VOORLETTERS, NAAM, GESLACHT, BEDRAG
```

how can i make it that I only see people with 2 or more 'boete'?

so that I get this as an answer

```
voorletters, naam, geslacht, boete    
B   Niewenburg  V   25.00
B   Niewenburg  V   140.00
D   Moerman V   35.00
D   Moerman V   50.00
DD  Cools   V   75.00
DD  Cools   V   85.00
E   Bakker, de  M   30.00
E   Bakker, de  M   35.00
E   Bakker, de  M   90.00
E   Bakker, de  M   95.00
```

Comment: Add `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`

Comment: @HoneyBadger I tried that but then ' R Permetier M 100.00'  who only has 1 still shows up :/

Comment: I wouldn't expect that from your sample data. You could also try `COUNT(boete) > 1` instead.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

use a subselect for get the people with two or more rows  in speler

```
SELECT VOORLETTERS, NAAM, GESLACHT, BEDRAG
FROM SPELER S
RIGHT JOIN BOETE B ON B.SPELERSNR = S.SPELERSNR
LEFT joiN BESTUURSLID BL ON BL.SPELERSNR = S.SPELERSNR
where s.naam in (select naam from (select naam, count(*) from speler group by name ) )
GROUP BY VOORLETTERS, NAAM, GESLACHT, BEDRAG
```